# management.server.port is not properly running after started spring boot AOT Graalvm application

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, graalvm-native-image

I have built an aot spring boot application and turn on management.server.port in order to separate service port(8080) and management port(8082) for calling liveness probe in kubernetes environment. this application is started well, however if i call a http://localhost:8082/actuator/health, it is not properly worked and print out this error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load 'DispatcherServlet.properties': class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

If i used to use same port for service and management, it is okay. properly works.

how am i doing to solve this problem ?

if i call a http://localhost:8082/actuator/health, i will reponse application's status.